# Multiple Linear Regression - the coefficient of X1 and value of y in the regression equation?

Tags: machine-learning

if we are performing multiple linear regression where `X1` and `X2` are independent variables and `Y` is the dependent variable. What can you say about the coefficient of `X1` and value of `Y` in the regression equation?

```
Y=β0+β1∗X1+β2∗X2
```

a)The predicted value of `Y` increases by `β1` for a unit increase in `X1`, irrespective of a change in `X2`.

b)The predicted value of `Y` increases by `β1` for a unit increase in `X1`, given `X2` does not change.

c)The predicted value of `Y` is `β1` when `X1=1`.

d)The predicted value of `Y` is `X2` when `X1=0`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be b), if X2 does not change:

(β0 + β *(x1+1) + β2*X2) - (β0 + β*x1 + β2*X2) = β1

Note whatever β1 is negative or positive, we always have one more β1.

For the rest options, they all fail to consider X1 and X2 simultaneously.